# Save buttons missing in django admin

Tags: mysql, django, admin, cloud9-ide

I have 2 simple models:

```
class Doll(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    doll_type = models.CharField(max_length=16, choices=DOLL_TYPE_CHOICES)
    mark = models.CharField(max_length=48, help_text='trademark on the body of the doll', default='')
    body = models.CharField(max_length=16, choices = BODY_CHOICES)
    factory = models.CharField(max_length=24, choices=FACTORY_CHOICES)

class DollLink(models.Model):
    doll = models.ForeignKey(Doll)
    link_type = models.CharField(max_length=16, choices=LINK_TYPE_CHOICES)
    url = models.URLField(default='')
```

In admin.py:

```
class DollLinkInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = DollLink
    fields = ('link_type', 'url')
    extra = 1

class DollAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('name', 'doll_type', 'body', 'factory')
    list_filter = ('doll_type', 'body', 'factory')
    inlines = (DollLinkInline,)

admin.site.register(Doll, DollAdmin)
```

If I want to add a new Doll or edit an existing one, then the save buttons are missing. It seems to me that it's related to inlines, cause if I remove the inline, the save buttons are back, and can add/edit Doll and DollLink separately. But if I put back the inline, again no save option. No js error on page.

I used django and inlines previously, and never experienced anything like that, nor found any similar issues with google.

My django version is 1.6.5, use MySQL and Cloud9 IDE.

Comment: i try you code it s run perfectly .

Comment: can you just comment out the `extra` arg for now, and try ?